# How to apply a function in N times whilst updating values in each iteration?

Tags: python, function

Please help me rewrite this function to be applicable not only for "twice" but for a flexible variable `n` or `times` maybe.

```
def apply_twice(func, *args):
    return func(func(*args))
```

I tried using a `for` loop but I ended up not applying the variable twice but executing it twice which had different results.

Comment: What are `*args`? do they change, or are they constant?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of `func` and of `args` when there are multiple args?

Comment: is your function is returning multiple values or single one ?

Comment: @trincot `func` would be `def doubling(x): return x +2` with the arg being x. I didn't use multiple here but I will have future functions with multiple ones

Comment: But... can you give an example of multiple arguments and the function? There are so many ways this can be interpreted... An example would clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a loop:

```
def apply_n_times(n, func, arg):
    for _ in range(n):
        arg = func(arg)
    return arg
```

If you have multiple args, then it depends on how you would propagate them. If for instance `func` is guaranteed to return a tuple with as many values as it gets, then:

```
def apply_n_times(n, func, *args):
    for _ in range(n):
        args = func(*args)
    return args
```

Comment: Yes I tried this, but this only works if the function has a single argument, not multiple ("*args"). Is there something like this for multiple arguments? *args = func(*args) doesn't work

Comment: See addition. This depends on what you want to happen with those args and how many values the function returns.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this if func only works with ints and no iterable arguments? I got an error regarding this. My func returns x + y

Comment: So what if n = 2? What will be the ***two*** arguments (x and y) for the *second* call? Really need a concrete example to know what you are after.